# How to enable backstage power (battery consumption) permission in Android 5.1?

Tags: android

[image]

I am running two services in background. This function is running good in all the devices. But in Vivo(5.1) and Oppo (5.1) the services stops after some time. The reason I found is to enable Back Stage power settings for the app. Since accesblity option is given from Android 6+ version so how I will open this screen or enable the option through code in lower version.

I have found no code to open the screen directly. Also, I don't have the device to see the package name. Please suggest.

Comment: Backstage power isn't a normal name for any setting, its something specific to the OEM.  But if this is just them renaming the battery usage whitelist (which I suspect it is)-  you can't set it programatically.  The user has to decide to turn it on for you.

Comment: Also, if you're running background services-  this setting won't stop the OS from killing them.  There's no way to do that.  A foreground service will be killed less often, but ,ay still be killed by the OS at any time.  You cannot assume you'll have a continuosuly running service on Android.